# Android: Getting Friends Birthday Using Graph API Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to get friends birth dates from facebook calendar using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984873/android-how-to-get-friends-birth-dates-from-facebook-calendar-using-graph-api)

Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13926065/1770916

I set permissions for getting friends birthday and list. code is below.

```
private void signInWithFacebook() {

    mSessionTracker = new SessionTracker(getBaseContext(), new StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        }
    }, null, false);

    String applicationId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(getBaseContext());
    mCurrentSession = mSessionTracker.getSession();

    if (mCurrentSession == null || mCurrentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
        Session session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext()).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        mCurrentSession = session;
    }

    if (!mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(MainActivity.this);

        if (openRequest != null) {
            openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
            openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "email", "user_location", "friends_birthday","read_friendlists" ));
            openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
            mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting only Friend ID and Name only.

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if (mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
       Request.executeMeRequestAsync(mCurrentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

              // callback after Graph API response with user object
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  Log.d("AL", user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getInnerJSONObject());
              }
            });


        Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(mCurrentSession, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                Log.d("AL",""+response.toString());
                for (int i=0;i<users.size();i++){
                    Log.d("AL",""+users.get(i).toString());
                    welcome.setText("Done");
                }

            }
        });
        }
  }
```

By using above code i am getting users additional things like email, birthday etc after adding permissions but not getting friends additional thinks like birthday.

where i am doing wrong???

Comment: Where's your call to `/me/friends?` Have you forgotten to add the extra fields you want returned in the `fields` parameter?

Answer (score 5):

For Getting Friends Information we need to get `HttpConnection` for following `url`

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="+ mAccessToken + "&fields=id,first_name,last_name,location,picture,birthday");
```

Here add Fields which you require.
I think it will work ..

Comment: getting empty data[]

Comment: @ M.J. i got empty array.. please do help me

Answer (score 0):

Here we get any thing for this

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=birthday,name&access_token="+ facebook.getAccessToken();
```

using this iam getting birthdays

```
 JSONObject JOAlbums = JAAlbums.getJSONObject(i);

 String date = DaysCount(JOAlbums.getString("birthday"));
```

Comment: getting empty data[]

Comment: @ NagarjunaReddy i got empty array.. please do help me